# Как использовать один диск в Raid массиве для отзеркаливания двух других?

Tags: raid

У меня два диска C и D (1 и 2 тб). Я хочу отзеркалить их на 4 тб. Я по теории отзеркалил диск C, на оставшемся месте можно отзеркалить диск D?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.